# MySQL - LIKE search better before join or after join with round trip?

Tags: mysql, join, indexing

Example:

Table 1 has 100k records, and has a varchar field with a unique index on it.
Table 2 has 1 million records, and relates to table 1 through a table1_id field with a many-to-one relationship, and has three varchar fields, only one of them unique. The engine in question is InnoDB so no fulltext indexes.

For argument's sake, assume these tables will grow to a maximum of 1 million and 10 million records respectively.

When I enter a search term into my form, I want it to search both tables across all four (total) available varchar fields with a LIKE and return only the records from Table1 - so I'm grouping by table1.id here. What I'm wondering is, is it more efficient to search the million records table first since it has only one field that needs to be searched and that one field is unique and then use the fetched IDs in an table1.id IN ({IDS}) query, or would it be better to join them outright and search them right then and there without making a round trip to the database?

In other words, when doing joins, does MySQL join according to the searched term, or join first and search later? That is, if I do a join and the LIKE on both tables in one query, will it first join them and then look through them for matching records, or will it join only the records it found to be matching?

Edit: I have made two sample tables and faked some data. This example query is a join and a LIKE search across all fields. For demo purposes I used LIKE '%q%' but in reality the q may be anything. The actual search on bogus 100k/1mil records took 0.03 seconds, MySQL says. Here is the explain: http://bit.ly/PsFBxK

Here is the explain query of searching just table2 on its one unique field: http://bit.ly/S06Hug and for this one to actually happen, MySQL says it took it 0.0135 seconds.

Comment: Do you have an example query and its EXPLAIN result? BTW, InnoDB's newer versions support fulltext search, so you might try to upgrade your MySQL if possible. http://blogs.innodb.com/wp/2011/12/innodb-full-text-search-in-mysql-5-6-4/

Comment: Upgrading is not an option unfortunately. I have posted some EXPLAIN results in the OP, though.